# Flink Job suddenly crashed with error: Encountered error while consuming partitions

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a streaming job failed after running for 1day and 10 hours. One of the subtasks suddenly failed and crashed the whole job. Since I set up a restart_strategy, the job automatically restarted but crashed again with the same error. I found the Task Manager's log that the failed task was on, but it is not very helpful for me to debug this. Can anyone suggest a better way? Thank you.

Job manager log around the failure:

```
2019-05-09 19:50:59,230 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator     - Triggering checkpoint 422 @ 1557431459229 for job 5834ff2d44c445d6390cab836df5eb36.
2019-05-09 19:51:08,257 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator     - Completed checkpoint 422 for job 5834ff2d44c445d6390cab836df5eb36 (892042793 bytes in 7841 ms).
2019-05-09 19:55:43,776 WARN  akka.remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor                        - Association with remote system [akka.tcp://flink-metrics@monarch-dev-021-20181106-data-slave-dev-0a025381.ec2.pin220.com:38803] has failed, address is now gated for [50] ms. Reason: [Disassociated] 
2019-05-09 19:55:43,812 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph        - Window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows(900000), PurgingTrigger, ComparableAggregator, PassThroughWindowFunction) -> Filter -> Numerator Results (41/64) (63c06366ff64c8a9c900b0f937ceab97) switched from RUNNING to FAILED.
org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.exception.RemoteTransportException: Connection unexpectedly closed by remote task manager 'monarch-dev-021-20181106-data-slave-dev-0a025381.ec2.pin220.com/10.2.83.129:33111'. This might indicate that the remote task manager was lost.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.CreditBasedPartitionRequestClientHandler.channelInactive(CreditBasedPartitionRequestClientHandler.java:136)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:224)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInputClosed(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:377)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInactive(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:342)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:224)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1429)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:947)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$8.run(AbstractChannel.java:822)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:463)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:884)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019-05-09 19:55:43,812 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph        - Job realtime experiments (5834ff2d44c445d6390cab836df5eb36) switched from state RUNNING to FAILING.
org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.exception.RemoteTransportException: Connection unexpectedly closed by remote task manager 'monarch-dev-021-20181106-data-slave-dev-0a025381.ec2.pin220.com/10.2.83.129:33111'. This might indicate that the remote task manager was lost.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.CreditBasedPartitionRequestClientHandler.channelInactive(CreditBasedPartitionRequestClientHandler.java:136)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:224)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInputClosed(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:377)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInactive(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:342)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:224)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1429)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:947)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$8.run(AbstractChannel.java:822)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:463)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:884)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

from the job manager log we know that the failed subtask is Window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows(900000), PurgingTrigger, ComparableAggregator, PassThroughWindowFunction) -> Filter -> Numerator Results (41/64) (63c06366ff64c8a9c900b0f937ceab97) using this I can locate the corresponding task manager log.

task manager log:

```
2019-05-08 07:34:05,224 WARN  org.apache.flink.metrics.MetricGroup                          - The operator name Window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows(900000), PurgingTrigger, ComparableAggregator, PassThroughWindowFunction) exceeded the 80 characters length limit and was truncated.
2019-05-08 07:34:05,226 INFO  org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.RocksDBKeyedStateBackend  - Initializing RocksDB keyed state backend.
2019-05-09 19:55:43,793 ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.PartitionRequestQueue  - Encountered error while consuming partitions
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:288)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1108)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:345)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:148)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:645)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:884)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019-05-09 19:55:43,798 INFO  org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.RocksDBKeyedStateBackend  - Deleting existing instance base directory /data/nvme1n1/nm-local-dir/usercache/yueliu/appcache/application_1550011960342_0581/flink-io-2317f89c-13b2-4530-8a96-a11cd2f67d1f/job_5834ff2d44c445d6390cab836df5eb36_op_WindowOperator_f625d779151677f0afde930cf114943c__41_64__uuid_d3fd1270-ad7a-47f4-b785-a533289e76cb.
2019-05-09 19:55:43,801 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                     - Window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows(900000), PurgingTrigger, ComparableAggregator, PassThroughWindowFunction) -> Filter -> Numerator Results (41/64) (63c06366ff64c8a9c900b0f937ceab97) switched from RUNNING to FAILED.
org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.exception.RemoteTransportException: Connection unexpectedly closed by remote task manager 'monarch-dev-021-20181106-data-slave-dev-0a025381.ec2.pin220.com/10.2.83.129:33111'. This might indicate that the remote task manager was lost.
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.CreditBasedPartitionRequestClientHandler.channelInactive(CreditBasedPartitionRequestClientHandler.java:136)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:224)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInputClosed(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:377)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInactive(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:342)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:224)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1429)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:947)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$8.run(AbstractChannel.java:822)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:463)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:884)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019-05-09 19:55:43,802 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                     - Freeing task resources for Window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows(900000), PurgingTrigger, ComparableAggregator, PassThroughWindowFunction) -> Filter -> Numerator Results (41/64) (63c06366ff64c8a9c900b0f937ceab97).
```

from the log we can see that it had been fine since 2019-05-08 07:34:05, until 2019-05-09 19:55:43 it suddenly had this issue and had been unable to recover from this failure.

Comment: What version of Flink is this? I'm wondering if this could be a known bug that has since been fixed.

Comment: @DavidAnderson  It's Flink 1.6.1 in maven pom.xml but accidentally used Flink-1.7.2 binary to launch the job.

Comment: I recompiled it with Flink 1.7.2 and launched it with 1.7.2 Flink, the issue still happens :(

Comment: update: I increased TM memory and this issue disappeared. Seems like off heap OOM.

Comment: I have increased TM memory to 6G, it doesn't work for me...

Comment: And do you get the reason leads to exceed TM memory limit in your program?

Comment: @jayWong If you are stuck with the same error, please ask a new question with your details. The latter clarifying comment is not unreasonable, but the first one 'it does not work for me' is something that the comments are not well suited for (and you can see potential answer holders did not notice it) -- Note that if you actually found an alternate answer, it would be nice if you could post it here as well!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, the asker resolved this as follows:

> I increased TM memory and this issue disappeared. Seems like off heap
> OOM.

Though probably not directly related it is of course also wise to avoid using mixed versions.