# Understanding Status.JVM.Memory.Direct.MemoryUsed in Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a flink job that kept crashing. I asked question on debugging that in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56071220/flink-job-suddenly-crashed-with-error-encountered-error-while-consuming-partiti?noredirect=1#comment98787904_56071220).

The issue was solved by increasing memory for task managers. I then checked the memory usage related metrics for all the containers at the time that this crash happened, and I saw 2 of them did have abnormal value for `Status.JVM.Memory.Direct.MemoryUsed`. I have a chart for that:
[jvm.memory.direct.memory_used.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2DCV.png)

From Flink official doc, it says `The biggest driver of Direct memory is by far the number of Flink’s network buffers, which can be configured.` However from task log I didn't see anything related to `not enough network buffer`. In order to prevent this from happening in the future, I would like to understand in detail what this portion of memory does in Flink and what could happen to these 2 outlier containers from the image. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

first, I've also need the behavior of TMs quitting without any logging of the problem, when it's an OutOfMemoryError.

Second, my experience with direct memory issues is that it didn't run out due to network buffers, but rather because I was using code that called through to compiled C code (Fasttext, in my case) which was allocating direct memory...are you sure you don't have a similar situation? Asking because usually Flink is good about not over-allocating memory - typically you get a failure like "Not enough memory for network buffers".

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I checked the log again and there is no "Not enough memory for network buffers", so I might write something malicious that keeps allocating direct memory. This is actually a new version of my job, for previous version it didn't have this issue. The main difference between the old and the new is that I replaced an interval join in the old version with a CoprocessFunction. 
Also I'm not very familiar with direct memory in Flink, from your experience can you list frequently seen mistakes in Flink job that could lead to this error? Or is there a systematic way to debug it?

Comment: Could this be caused by unbounded memory usage of RocksDB?

Comment: RocksDB can use direct memory via Java NIO/direct buffers, yes. I'd check how much direct memory is initially available to the TaskManager (the `-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=<blah>` parameter used when launching the TM). This article also has good info on using heap dumps to figure out who is allocating memory: https://dzone.com/articles/troubleshooting-problems-with-native-off-heap-memo